# Why do we need to set DerivedObject.prototype.constructor to DerivedObject?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, prototypal-inheritance

Per MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance), it is suggested that `Teacher.prototype.constructor` should be reset to `Teacher`. `Teacher` inherits from `Person` object using prototypal inheritance. I am trying to understand what can possibly break if this step is not followed.

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/bdevapatla/pen/ZoRRbG) that I setup, where I did not follow this step, however things seem to work fine. I think I am missing something. Can someone please help?

Comment: It’s expected that an object’s `constructor` property reflects its constructor. I’m not aware of anything built-in that requires this, but you may as well do it. (Other tools might need it; for example, `Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor)` in a custom error type.)